# How to sort with predetermined order in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

My dataset `df` look like this:

```
date           high
2018-01-01     -1
2018-01-02     1
2018-01-03     -2
2018-01-04     0
...., ....
2018-12-31     1
```

Where,

```
-2 >= high <= 2
```

`high` is always between `-2` and `2`

I want to sort the value of `high` in the following pattern:

To start, Group all `0` and sort by date and so on for other values.

Sort the `high` value in the following order:

```
0
1
-1
2
-2
```

It would be best if it's flexible enough that I can change the order if required.

I know how to sort in `asc` or `desc` by doing this:

```
df.sort_values(by='high', ascending=False)
```

Could you please help me solve how do I sort using predetermined values?

Comment: `df.sort_values(['high', 'date'], ascending=[True,True])`?

Comment: df = df.sort_values(['high', 'date'], ascending=[True,True])

Comment: Can you come up with a [mcve] ?

Comment: The proposed code does exactly what you are describing. I think you are not correctly explaining your problem.

Comment: @Akaisteph7 everyone, I updated the question.

Comment: `df.assign(temp=df['high'].abs()).sort_values(['temp', 'date']).drop('temp', axis=1)`

Comment: @Erfan good solution. But this does not satisfy OP's requirement of `"It would be best if it's flexible enough that I can change the order if required."`. It is best to Use a  `Categorical Series` in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to define `high` as a [**`Categorical Series`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/categorical.html) with `order` as your choice.

```
order = [0 , 1, -1, 2, -2]
df['high'] = pd.Categorical(df['high'], order)
df.sort_values(['high', 'date'])
```

Output:

```
        date    high
3   2018-01-04  0
1   2018-01-02  1
4   2018-12-31  1
0   2018-01-01  -1
2   2018-01-03  -2
```